# Обратиться к гетеру в GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

Делал по примеру, но для recyclerView

Пытаюсь реализовать, по нажатию получать элемент из списка(url)

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.putExtra("video_link", imageUploads.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUrl());
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

И вроде всё так, но `getAdapterPosition` выделяет красным. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

И правильно ли будет поступить следующим образом, заменив на

```
ImageUpload imageUploads = new ImageUpload();
intent.putExtra("video_link", imageUploads.getUrl());
```

Comment: а по какому событию у вас происходит обращение к элементу GridView?

Comment: @miha_dev onClick

Comment: так вы onClick на каждый элемент вешаете? не проще повесить onItemClickListener:

Comment: `gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // do something
        }
    });`

Comment: @miha_dev а какая разница в принципе? и в методе onClick  при сильном желании я могу определить position.

Comment: тогда в чем ваш вопрос?